# NDSolve SetDelayed error

Tags: warning-messages, finite-difference-method

I'm trying to calculate the first derivative of a function at a number of points using the 4-th order finite difference matrix, and then multiplying it with the function values at that point. I wrote this module (for arbitrary order of derivative), then defined an example grid and function to test it:
`` der4[gridpoints_,values_,order_]:= Module[{x=gridpoints, y=values, k=order}, de=NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[k],N[x],"DifferenceOrder"->4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"//Normal//MatrixForm; de.N[y]] ``

`number=31;`
`f[x_]:=Exp[-8*x^2];`
`grid=Subdivide[-1, 1, number];`
`val=f[grid];`
`der4[grid,val,1]`

I get a matrix that at least looks like what it needs to, but also the following error:

`SetDelayed::write: Tag Plus in (-2 dx+dx (-1+x)+x3)[x_] is Protected.`

and this string `(-2 dx+dx (-1+x)+x3)[x_]` appears between the multiplication of the matrix and the values vector, can anyone help with this?

Comment: @DanielHuber I did it and I get the same error. Besides, de4 needs to be a matrix, so that it can be properly multiplied with the values from the left.

Comment: Unable to reproduce after removing `MatrixForm`. Try with a fresh kernel.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Matrix not Vector: If you write: de= ... //MatrixForm then you get MatrixForm[...] and not a list of list of lists (matrix). Therefore delete the MatrixForm.

Comment: I deleted MatrixForm and used kernel (I was running everything as a Script), and it seems to work, thank you both! Curiously enough, I ran another script that was running perfectly fine yesterday, and the same error popped up randomly, making one of my plots disappear, any clue why this happens? So that I know what to avoid in the future